# What is "Copy all NTFS Permissions" during copy files and folders with "Total Commander"

Tags: windows, file-management, storage, total-commander

I am using windows os as my device.
I want to copy all files and folders from my internal hard drive to external one using `Total commander` program.
The reason of using `Total commander` is copy long file names that windows os can not handle it.
During copy files and folders with total commander there is an option to "Copy NTFS permissions" too.
What is this check box?
Is it necessary for my External hard drive?
Should i check it or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option is for when copying from NTFS to NTFS.

With the option ticked, the file permissions on the source file are
copied as-is. This may cause a problem if the target folder has
different permissions, for example a different owner, which may
prevent this owner from using the files. It is less important
if you are the owner of both source and target.

With the option unticked, the copied file will inherit the permissions
of the folder to which it is copied, meaning that it will have no
permissions of its own that are different than that of the target folder.

Addition by @Tonny:

To add: With the checkbox OFF it has the same behaviour that Microsoft's own File Explorer has. With the checkbox ON you may need admin-rights to apply the permissions on the target files and the copying (when doing a large amounts of files) is a bit slower. For most people keeping this OFF is the best option. The ON setting is mostly of interest if you need to re-create a source folder-tree on a target disk exactly, including original permissions. Most users will never have a need for that.

Comment: So i should leave it blank during copy files to external hard drive. Am i right? Because i want to use that hard in different systems. You really have a high reputation by the way. Jesus. Thanks for helping people.

Comment: To add: With the checkbox OFF it has the same behavior that Microsofts own File Explorer has. With the checkbox ON you may need admin-rights to apply the permissions on the target files and the copying (when doing a large amounts of files) is a bit slower.
For most people keeping this OFF is the best option. The ON setting is mostly of interest if you need to re-create a source folder-tree on a target disk exactly, including original permissions. Most users will never have a need for that.

Comment: @SilverLight To copy files to a transfer-disk (or USB stick) to be used on different computers this REALLY should be OFF.

Comment: @Tonny Really appreciate for help and comment. Can total commander copy all files and folders in the right way? I do n't want to lose anything in the future.

Comment: @Tonny: I added your comment to my answer, if you don't mind. Too good to stay as a comment.